# How to initialise one array using another constexpr array in a static manner

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

I have a `constexpr` array like this:

```
constexpr std::array<int, 4> BASES_TO_CHECK = { 8, 16, 32, 64 };
```

I would like to do something akin to:

```
std::array<std::thread, BASES_TO_CHECK.size()> calc;
for(size_t i = 0; i<BASES_TO_CHECK.size(); ++i)
{
    calc[i]=std::thread(calculate<BASES_TO_CHECK[i]>,  std::ref(recordMap[BASES_TO_CHECK[i]]),  std::ref(counterMap.at(BASES_TO_CHECK[i])),  std::ref(done));
}
```

However, as the variable is used as a template parameter, so that won't work. I have ended up doing this:

```
std::array<std::thread, BASES_TO_CHECK.size()> calc = {
    std::thread(calculate<BASES_TO_CHECK[0]>,  std::ref(recordMap[BASES_TO_CHECK[0]]),  std::ref(counterMap.at(BASES_TO_CHECK[0])),  std::ref(done)),
    std::thread(calculate<BASES_TO_CHECK[1]>,  std::ref(recordMap[BASES_TO_CHECK[1]]),  std::ref(counterMap.at(BASES_TO_CHECK[1])),  std::ref(done)),
    std::thread(calculate<BASES_TO_CHECK[2]>,  std::ref(recordMap[BASES_TO_CHECK[2]]),  std::ref(counterMap.at(BASES_TO_CHECK[2])),  std::ref(done)),
    std::thread(calculate<BASES_TO_CHECK[3]>,  std::ref(recordMap[BASES_TO_CHECK[3]]),  std::ref(counterMap.at(BASES_TO_CHECK[3])),  std::ref(done))
};
```

And this works, but is relying on me not changing the number of elements in the `BASES_TO_CHECK` without also manually updating the part of the code where `calc` array is initialised.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what you mean when you say `the variable is used as a template parameter`?

Comment: @AndyG There is a template parameter, and i needed to be able to change it sequentually (see example, that was already in the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<std::size_t... i>
std::array<std::thread, BASES_TO_CHECK.size()> gen_impl(std::index_sequence<i...>) {
    return {
                std::thread(calculate<BASES_TO_CHECK[i]>,
                            std::ref(recordMap[BASES_TO_CHECK[i]]),
                            std::ref(counterMap.at(BASES_TO_CHECK[i])),
                            std::ref(done)
                           )...
           };
}

auto calc = gen_impl(std::make_index_sequence<BASES_TO_CHECK.size()>{});
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. Would i need to make everything global for this? `BASES_TO_CHECK` can be global, it's even better that way, but `recordMap` and `counterMap` are local variables.

Comment: Ok I have made `BASES_TO_CHECK` global, and added passed by reference parameters `recordMap`, `counterMap`, and `done` (as they are suppose to be local variables). Thanks a lot. It would be nice to have explanation as to what is happening, but i'll try to read it up myself.

Comment: Well your `recordMap`, `counterMap` and `done` can still be passed as parameters to the `gen_impl` function.